# Copying Data between table without identity column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two table and I need to copy the data across from SRCServiceUsers to Clients

Everytime I run it I get the following:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK_Clients'. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'dbo.Clients'. The
>   statement has been terminated.  The
>   Primary key ClientId field is not an
>   identity column and therefore requires
>   filling

To date I have the following

```
insert into Clients(ClientID, Title, Forenames, FamilyName,
                    [Address], Town, County, PostCode,
                    PhoneNumber, StartDate)
    SELECT (Select Max(Clients.ClientID)+ 1,
            SRCServiceUsers.Title,
            SRCServiceUsers.[First Names],
            SRCServiceUsers.Surname,
            --BUILD UP MUITIPLE COLUMNS
            SRCServiceUsers.[Property Name] + ', ' + SRCServiceUsers.Street + ', ' 
               +  SRCServiceUsers.Suburb as [Address],
            SRCServiceUsers.Town,
            SRCServiceUsers.County,
            SRCServiceUsers.Postcode,
            SRCServiceUsers.Telephone,
            SRCServiceUsers.[Start Date]
    FROM 
       srcsERVICEuSERS
```

How can I autoincrement the PK field - CLientID when inserting the data?

Many thanks

Andrew

Comment: Why isn't `ClientID` an identity column if you just want arbitrary incrementing numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @MaxClientId INT

SELECT @MaxClientId = MAX(ClientID) /*SERIALIZABLE will prevent any inserts above this*/
FROM Clients

INSERT INTO Clients(....)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) + @MaxClientId...
FROM srcsERVICEuSERS

COMMIT
```